# Real word for "productionalize"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, synonyms

I am looking for an alternative to the term *productionalize.* I believe the generally accepted definition of the word says that it means "to make a software prototype ready for production". In a sentence:

> In our work we will **productionalize** the ideas of XYZ to great effect.

Is there such a term that can be used as a drop-in replacement?

Comment: Hi @strugs, can you give more detail of what 'productionalize' means to you? For example, making pseudo-code or prototype code ready for a prod environment is just called making it 'production-strength'. Taking ideas, and making production-ready software is just 'implementing' them. If someone has ideas for an app, and you make it happen, you 'actualize' them. TBH, 'productionalize' sounds like exactly the sort of naff jargon that techies love: it's probably a 'keeper' ;)

Comment: ***implement**?*

Comment: In a (mainly) hardware engineering sense this is what production engineers do (with help from both manufacturing and design). I haven't come across a better word in that sense

Comment: "Commercialize"  comes close.    But in the long run I'd toss the entire sentence in favor of "Our job is to convert proof-of-concept systems into manufacturable, saleable objects."

Comment: *productize*......

Comment: @ArchContrarian, your definition of making "code ready for a prod environment" is exactly my understanding of the word! I really like using it in techie contexts, but it's pretty, uh, unacceptable to put in a grant or technical paper.

Comment: @ChrisH I agree that commercialize comes close, but it has some monetary connotations that productionalize doesn't.

Comment: @strugs ... so why don't you say, "...implement XYZ's ideas to production-strength"? ... oh, wait: on second thoughts, 'production-ready' might be an alternative. Like, "we will use the funding to production-ready the app..."?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea of *"put into production"* in the software development sense is very different than in the manufacturing sense.

Therefore, I would strongly argue that `productionalize` and `productionalization` are proper words that have yet to become commonplace outside of tech, but for which no other *proper*  word exists.

- `productize`, as suggested in the comments, conveys a different idea: that of making into a product. It implies creation and perhaps commerce.
- `productionalize` conveys solidifying the quality and modifying (evolving?) the idea's use. While a product may come from this effort, that is not necessary for it to *"go into production"*.

The closest other word that already exists might be `operationalize`, but if `operationalize` can come into being, then so can `productionalize`

Answer (score 6):

The word you are looking for (in use since the 1930s) is **productionize**, according to [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/productionize):

> (also **productionise**) [with object] To produce for general use; to put into production.

Attribution: "Productionize | Definition of Productionize in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed April 04, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/productionize.

Comment: Answers need to be referenced, especially in such a case as this where the word is obscure.

Answer (score 0):

"actualize" is possible though somewhat less specific to the case

Answer (score -3):

the word you are looking for is "produce".  Just like the correct alternative for "solutionize" is "solve".

Making a meal out of words has been going on a while (apologise = sorry).  It has only recently become more prevalent as big wigs in commerce use them, and followers inanely copy that use.

Imagineize if we totalize the usagization of them in our vocabulization.

Comment: -1. If you come down from your pulpit rant against big words and put the solution you've proposed into the OP's sentence, you'll realise it doesn't work: "In our work we will produce the ideas of XYZ to great effect." *Produce* does **not** mean *make something ready for production*.